# Regex: Match either of 2 groups, but not both

Tags: regex

I need to match a string that has either a prefix, or a suffix.

So far, I've done this:

`(?i)(?:(?:Localized(?:App)?String\(@))?\"(.+?)\".(?:localized)?`

Testing this regex against the scenario below, it works well, except for the first line, where I should have no matches:

```
print("Error: should NOT capture!")
NSLocalizedAppString(@"Contextual Menu",nil)];
self.setTitleStates(["Unmute1".localized, "Mute".localized])
NSApplication.localizedString("Paused", comment: "")
print("Remove from Set".localized)
```

How do I mutually exclude the prefix group with the suffix group?

Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Interesting approach, wouldn't have thought of it. Post this is an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?si)Localized(?:App)?String\(@?"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"\.localized
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/et7Yus/3). *Details*:

- `(?si)` - dot now matches line breaks and `i` makes the pattern case insensitive
- `Localized` - a word
- `(?:App)?` - an optional `App` string
- `String\(` - a `String(` text
- `@?` - an optional `@`
- `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - a `"..."` string literal pattern with escape sequences support
- `|` - or
- `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - a `"..."` string literal pattern with escape sequences support
- `\.localized` - `.localized` string.